# Why can't we use access modifiers and static keyword for creating an object in C#?

Tags: c#

for example :-

```
class Something 
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

class Program 
{
    public/private/internal/protected/protected internal static Something s = new Something(); //compilation error why? 
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  You *can* have access modifiers for fields.  Can you post a properly formatted code example that produces just the error you are seeing?

Comment: Give us the exact error message you get.

Comment: I got the anwser. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can. Try it out:

```
internal class Something 
{
    ...
}

class Program 
{
    internal static Something s = new Something(); //no compilation error 
}
```

You're probably having issues with conflicting access modifiers. The following doesn't compile because the access for the object and the class contradict:

```
internal class Something 
{
    ...
}

public class Program 
{
    public static Something s = new Something(); // compilation error: class 'Something' is internal but 's' is public
}
```

Comment: @user1892538 It doesn't. Maybe you forgot to make `Program` public?

Comment: Yeah i got it..Thank you :)